# Image saved into database not showing

Tags: java, mysql, blob

So i'm tryna save a blob image into database and display it once i click"view" href. But I don't know why the pic cannot be seen. It saves in mysql database tho...

retrieve_image.jsp:

```
     <%@ page import="java.sql.*,model.Upload,java.io.*,java.util.*" %> 
        <HTML>
         <table border="1">
         <tr><th>ID</th><th>Image</th></tr>
           <%
          try{      
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/backup","root","mysql");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            String strQuery = "select * from contacts";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(strQuery);
            while(rs.next()){
               %>
              <tr>
              <td><%=rs.getInt("contact_id")%></td>
              <td>
                <img src="RetrieveImages.java?id=<%=rs.getInt(1)%>" width="100" height="100">

        </a></td>
              </tr>
              <%
            }
            rs.close();
            con.close();
            stmt.close();
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
            e.getMessage();
          }
          %>
         </table>
        </HTML>
```

RetrieveImages is a servlet which has request dispatcher that goes to...

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Blob"%>
<%@page import="java.io.OutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@ page import="model.Upload" %>

<%
String contact_id = request.getParameter("contact_id");
    String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/backup";
    String dbUser = "root";
    String dbPass = "mysql";

    Connection con = null;

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from contacts where contact_id=?");
        ps.setString(1, contact_id);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            Blob blob = rs.getBlob("photo");
            byte byteArray[] = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());

            response.setContentType("image");
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
            os.write(byteArray);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        if(con != null){
            try{
                con.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
 %>
```

In my java bean i have contact_id and photo as attribuites

Comment: This is `jsp`... What content type is "image"?

Comment: Refer this code... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29328851/arguments-can-not-be-larger-than-the-blobs-length 
it was working for me